# Defining a custom Blend Function (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, graphics, alphablending

For implementing a physically accurate motion blur by actually rendering at intermediate locations, it seems that to do this correctly I need a special blending function. Additive blending would only work on a black background, and the standard "transparency" function `(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` may look okay for small numbers of samples, but it is physically inaccurate because samples rendered at the end will contribute more to the resulting color.

The function I need has to produce a color which is the weighted average of the original and destination colors, depending on the number of samples covering a fragment. However I can generalize this to better account for rendering differences between samples: Suppose I am to render a blurred object n times. Treating color as a 3-vector, Let `D` be the color `DEST - SRC`. I want each render to add `D/n` to the source color.

Can this be done using the fixed-function pipeline? [The glBlendFunc reference](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) is rather cryptic, at least to me. It seems like this can be done either trivially or is impossible. It seems like I would want to set alpha to `1/n`. For the behavior I just described, am I in need of a `GL_DEST_MINUS_SRC_COLOR` option?

I also have a related question: At which stage does this blending operation occur? Before or after the fragment shader program? Would i be able to access the source and destination colors in a fragment shader?

I know that one way to accomplish what I want is by using an accumulation buffer. I do not want to do this because it is a waste of memory and fillrate.

Comment: You *have* to do this with the fixed function pipeline as there is no blend shader yet. Also blending occurs after fragment shading. At no other stage in the pipeline you know the value of a pixel.

Comment: After some thinking: I don't see how you could put state into the BlendFunc. Usually you can tune it with BlendEquation but that wont help you here as the blending part of the pipeline has no notion of `number of rendering passes`. However, you can use a fragment shader that computes the right alpha value with the help of a uniform.

Comment: Couldn't you do it in a fragment program yourself? You could put the input textures into texture units 1 through 8 (or whatever the max on your card is) and blend them there.

Comment: @pmr, could I perhaps calculate the color depending on which pass it is?

Comment: You cannot do "physically accurate motion blur" by just blurring specific objects. The entire scene must be rendered multiple times.

Comment: I think a fragment shader may be able to accomplish this task. I have to think on it some more.

Comment: @NicolBolas, My idea is to render objects in motion multiple times (so that the entire scene need not be rendered multiple times) and then using camera motion to generate a fullscreen blur after rendering the scene to texture.

Comment: @StevenLu: But that's no more "physically accurate" than any other forms of hacks. I'm just saying that it isn't particularly accurate.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not sure why I let the conversation stop, but anyway, there are various ways to improve on performance compared to the naive "accumulator buffer" technique of rendering something N times temporally to produce one final frame by averaging. For example, something not moving can be rendered just once, and only something moving sufficiently quickly would necessarily incur the full texel-sampling cost of the motion blur. I was using the concept of maintaining some ratio of number of blurring samples w.r.t. the pixel-length of the blur. The quality is easy to tweak dynamically as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using to implement my effect is a combination of additive blending and a render target that I access as a texture from the fragment shader.